# Running Gemfire Query during Transaction on field without Query Index

Tags: gemfire, geode

We are seeing below exception when querying a field in a region during GF transaction in a gemfire **client**.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntrySnapshot cannot be cast to com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion$NonTXEntry

at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet$EntriesIterator.moveNext(EntriesSet.java:183) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet$EntriesIterator.<init>(EntriesSet.java:121) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntriesSet.iterator(EntriesSet.java:85) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.ResultsCollectionWrapper.iterator(ResultsCollectionWrapper.java:181) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.QRegion.iterator(QRegion.java:225) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.doNestedIterations(CompiledSelect.java:712) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.doIterationEvaluate(CompiledSelect.java:577) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.CompiledSelect.evaluate(CompiledSelect.java:413) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.executeUsingContext(DefaultQuery.java:529) 
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:365)
```

From our trial and error, It only happens when it meets below criteria

1. **Transaction** is **running**:
   i.e. called `gemfireCache.getCacheTransactionManager().begin()` and then execute the query
2. **Not create Functional index** for the Query/Field:
   i.e. `QueryService.createIndex(String, String, String)` is not called on the specific field during init

<s>3. where condition has a **field that can be null** in the region data:
i.e. if run `"SELECT * FROM /REGIONNAME WHERE fieldName = $1"`, if `fieldName` is null in some entry, it throws the above exception, otherwise, it is fine.</s>

We are using compiled Query acquired from `QueryService.newQuery("SELECT * FROM /REGIONNAME WHERE fieldName = $1")`. and the queryservice is a local one if I am not wrong, not running query on the server.

We are using Gemfire 8.2.1

comment below if you need more information.

--- Update 05/12/2016 ---

Finally get some time to put together a simple test case to illustrate the problem:

I Launch the process using JUnit, just a personal habit. The first test case start a server with co-located locator on port 40001

The second test case start a client process and runs a query without index within transaction.

```java
public class GemfireQueryInTXTest {

@Test
public void startServer() throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    System.setProperty("gemfirePropertyFile", "query_in_tx/gfserver-query-in-tx.properties");
    String file = DistributedSystem.getPropertyFileURL().getFile();
    props.load(new FileReader(file));

    Cache cache = new CacheFactory(props).create();
    RegionFactory<String, ValueEntry> factory = cache
            .<String, ValueEntry>createRegionFactory("REPLICATE")
            .setKeyConstraint(String.class)
            .setValueConstraint(ValueEntry.class);

    Region<String, ValueEntry> valueEntryRegion = factory.create("VALUEENTRY");

    valueEntryRegion.put("first", new ValueEntry("firstEntry", "NotNull"));
    valueEntryRegion.put("second", new ValueEntry("secondEntry", null));

    CacheServer server = cache.addCacheServer();
    server.setPort(40000);

    server.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000000L);
}

@Test
public void testRunningQueryDuringTransactionOnNullableField() throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    System.setProperty("gemfirePropertyFile", "query_in_tx/gemfire-query-in-tx.properties");
    String file = DistributedSystem.getPropertyFileURL().getFile();
    props.load(new FileReader(file));

    ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory(props).create();
    ClientRegionFactory<String, ValueEntry> factory = cache
            .<String, ValueEntry>createClientRegionFactory("DEFAULT")
            .setKeyConstraint(String.class)
            .setValueConstraint(ValueEntry.class);

    Region<String, ValueEntry> valueEntryRegion = factory.create("VALUEENTRY");
    valueEntryRegion.registerInterest(".*", InterestResultPolicy.KEYS_VALUES);

    CacheTransactionManager cacheTransactionManager = cache.getCacheTransactionManager();

    QueryService localQueryService = cache.getLocalQueryService();
    Query query = localQueryService.newQuery("SELECT * from /VALUEENTRY WHERE nullable = $1");
    // No Exception will be thrown if create index for the field (uncomment below);
    // localQueryService.createIndex("IndexName", "nullable", "/VALUEENTRY");

    // ... Or run without transaction (comment below tx opening and closing)
    cacheTransactionManager.begin();
    System.out.println("Before Query Executed");
    query.execute(new Object[]{"1"});
    System.out.println("After Query Executed");
    cacheTransactionManager.commit();
}
}
```

Domain Object: ValueEntry.java

```java
public class ValueEntry implements DataSerializable {
private String notNull;
private String nullable;

public ValueEntry() {
}

public ValueEntry(String notNull, String nullable) {
    this.notNull = notNull;
    this.nullable = nullable;
}

public String getNotNull() {
    return notNull;
}

public String getNullable() {
    return nullable;
}

@Override
public void toData(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
    DataSerializer.writeString(notNull, dataOutput);
    DataSerializer.writeString(nullable, dataOutput);
}

@Override
public void fromData(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    this.notNull = DataSerializer.readString(dataInput);
    this.nullable = DataSerializer.readString(dataInput);
}
}
```

Server Proerties and xml:

```xml
cache-xml-file=query_in_tx\\cache-server.xml
start-locator=40001
locators=localhost[40001]
log-file=logs\\server.log
log-level=config
mcast-port=0
name=server

<cache>
<serialization-registration>
    <instantiator id="999">
        <class-name>com.testing.gemfire.domain.ValueEntry</class-name>
    </instantiator>
</serialization-registration>
</cache>
```

Client Proerties and xml:

```xml
cache-xml-file=query_in_tx\\cache-query-in-tx.xml
log-disk-space-limit=100
log-file-size-limit=20
log-file=logs\\cache.log
log-level=config
mcast-port=0
name=gemfire-playground

<client-cache>
    <pool name="Zero" subscription-enabled="true" read-timeout="3000"
          retry-attempts="5" socket-buffer-size="65536">
        <locator host="localhost" port="40001" />
    </pool>

    <region-attributes id="DEFAULT" refid="CACHING_PROXY" pool-name="Zero"/>
</client-cache>
```

Comment: Have you tried using PDX?

Comment: @Swapnil we did not use that since beginning, so don't think thats going to happen considering the scale of the project and the effort to switch. For this specific problem, we workaround by creating functional index on the field. But I am just wondering whether it is an interesting bug in gemfire? or I miss out certain information in the documentation which makes me use it in the wrong way?

Comment: I have updated my question with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicated with Pivotal team, this turns out to be a bug in Gemfire client. As mentioned in the question description, creating index will stop this exception from being thrown.

I will update again if it is fixed in the future version.